# Issue url scheme of code-igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form like

```
<form action="abc/1" method="post">

</form>
```

I want every time this form is submitted my URL remains same like suppose my current URL was

```
http://localhost/abc/1 after form submit it should be again 
http://localhost/abc/1

but instead this it become
http://localhost/abc/1
http://localhost/abc/abc/1
http://localhost/abc/abc/abc/1 each time I press submit button in form.
```

its something related to URL schemes of mvc  in code-igniter

Comment: /abc/1 instead of abc/1

Comment: actually my url was http://localhost:8080/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/home/authenticateUser/1 and i want to remain on this url by putting / thing it becomes http://localhost:8080/authenticateUser/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of your form is relative to your current position.

If you are on `http://example.com/contact` and your form's action is set to `contact/send` the form well send to `http://example.com/contact/contact/send` Now, this would be easy fixed by either removing the `contact/` part form the action attribute or by adding a `/` in the beginning of your action attribute, so the path is absolute - `/contact/send`.

Doing this in CodeIgniter should be relatively easy, as you can use the [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to point to the correct URL's in your application.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('abc/1'); ?>" method="post">

</form>
```

This example will always point you to the page relative to your base_url and index_page settings in `application/config/config.php`.

In your case, mentioned in the comments, something along with `<?php echo site_url('home/authenticateUser/' . $user_id); ?>` would probably be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
<form action="/abc/1" method="post">

</form>
```

or else you better to use site_url like

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('abc/1');?>" method="post">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the action from "abc/1" to "/abc/1" will work, but if you are building your app in a subdirectory, as is usually the case on a localhost development environment, this will revert to your htdocs folder, as opposed to your required folder.

I would recommend one of two options:

1. `<form action="<?php echo base_url(abc/1); ?" method="post">`
2. `<?php form_open('abc/1')' ?>`

Number 2 is the better one, as it works with CodeIgniter's CSRF functionality, and adds the base_url() automatically.

Hope this helps.